# What is the ace_order column in Spring ACL table?

Tags: spring, spring-security, acl

Can you tell what does it mean `ace_order` column in the table `acl_entry`? I know that it must be unique for the same `acl_object_identity`, but I don't know meaning of this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules are processed in **order**, so the first pattern/method match determines which security expression will be used to make the access decision. Therefore, place more specific patterns before more general patterns.

Comment: An example will explains the above well